# ability to capture on what user was doing on the web page

Tags: asp.net, user-input, user-experience

Is there a tool to capture actual user experience on a my website. I would like to capture things like customerid, which button they clicked, information in their cookie, query string etc. etc. etc. Is there a tool that I can plug into my website that would provide this information for a web page and dump into nice columns in sql server table? I would like to be able to …

1. go through the logs.
2. Pick a particular log entry
3. Zoom into that log entry and look into more detailed information like querystring, cookie data etc.
4. Be able to capture all the information on what user was doing on that page when the exception happened.

Is it possible? Is there a tool out there for this?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe google analytic, or woopra (there is the basic for free) ?

Comment: You can view querystring and form data with elmah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article describes using [Google In-Page Analytics](http://www.iblogzone.com/2011/05/google-in-page-analytics-personalized-heatmap.html) to generate heat maps for where users click on your web pages but this is aggregated rather than for specific users. In addition to the normal hits GA records for a page you can also add custom hits based on client-side interactions using a technique similar to [tracking outbound links](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527). We used this with the [GA Funnel](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55580) to track progress through a sign-up form.

Having [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) installed is unbelievably useful for a wide range of reasons and will be well worth configuring if you haven't already.

I found [WebLog Expert](http://www.weblogexpert.com/info/IISLogs.htm) to be very handy for analysing the IIS logs at an aggregate level.

I'm not aware of any one product that does all three elements and none specifically well at the per user level.